# How to execute curl script from cygwin

Tags: curl, cygwin

I am trying to execute curl scripts from cygwin terminal this way,

```
./curl-get-users
```

I am having webservice request in the script.

Response is not getting displayed in console.

Is this the right way to execute curl script from cygwin?

Or should i use any other package in cygwin?

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Please show your curl script!

Comment: curl http://localhost:8080/Sample/rest/users

Answer (score 0):

this a basic example:

```
bash <(curl -s http://www.mywebsite.com/script.txt)
```

so, based on your url must be:

```
bash <(curl -s http://localhost:8080/Sample/rest/users)
```